# 'initwindow' doesn't open a window in code:blocks c++

Tags: c++, codeblocks, bgi

I wanted to use the code blocks to draw circles. I downloaded BGI and put the files of the BGI in the correct places in the code blocks folder (and also changed the complier settings from codeblocks). However, when calling the initwindow from the main in the codeblocks, nothing happend (there isn't any window);

```
#include <iostream>
#include <graphics.h>

int main()
{
    initwindow(900,900);
    circle(90,90,90);
    return 0;

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you a time traveller from 1995? The last version of BGI is from 1997. We're in 2020 now.

Comment: So do you have another recommendation for graphics in code-blocks?

Comment: Sure, just use the normal [Programming reference for the Win32 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/). Available with either MinGW or VS (or even the antiquated Windows SDK 7.1 that provides VS10 compiler)

Comment: @noamishal Try to use 
`int gd=DETECT,gm; 
initgraph(&gd,&gm,"");` instead of `initwindow(900,900);`.

Comment: Click on the BGI tag and you can read: _Borland graphics interface (graphics.h) is a legacy library for 2D graphics similar to nowadays GDI._ One alternative option. Read in Wikipedia about BGI and you will find SDL and OpenGL. And there are many more.